# Have to update datatable and recordset in vb6

Tags: vb6, datatable, recordset

I am currently using a datable on a form with an adodb connection which runs fine. However it does not detect changes to update. I want to put 2 recordsets to compare  the two as I need the column name and changed column info the old and the new, so I put a column in the recordset.

If someone could shoe me how to do the loop or whatever is needed to get this done please!!!

Comment: Please post some sample code so we can understand what you're talking about.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if addresses your problem exactly... if you want to add a column to a recordset that can be updated *in your code only* (i.e. cannot be written back to the database because it did not come from the database) then you can use the MsDataShape OLE DB provider with its `SHAPE...APPEND` syntax e.g.

```
Sub MSDataShape_AddNewCol()

  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  With rs
    .ActiveConnection = _
        "Provider=MSDataShape;" & _
        "Data Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Tempo\My_Access_DB.mdb"

    .Source = _
        "SHAPE {" & _
        " SELECT ExistingField" & _
        " FROM ExistingTable" & _
        " ORDER BY ExistingField" & _
        "} APPEND NEW adNumeric(5, 4) AS NewField"

    .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic

    .Open

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To .RecordCount - 1
      .Fields("NewField").Value = Round(.Fields("ExistingField").Value, 4)
      .MoveNext
    Next

    rs.Save "C:\rs.xml", adPersistXML  ' 

  End With
End Sub
```